# Do I need to reset IIS after sharing WebApp folder on the web server?

Tags: iis, application-pools, iis-10

I've recently installed new web application software onto a new server (Win 2016, IIS 10.0).
When I access the webpage not all the items load up and I get http 401.2 errors on those items that failed to load -  I suspect it is because I haven't created a Share on the web server for access to the WebApp folder.

Once I create the new Share on the web server, do I then need to Stop and Start the linked Application Pool in IIS ? Or refresh the IIS Connection 
Is there a specific order I need to do this in? Stop App Pool -> Create Share -> Start App Pool

Or should everything just be fine and dandy after I create the Share - ie I don't need to do anything?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on your application. If it is trying to connect to your share in every run, it may work straight when the share is reachable. If it's using cached errors (or timouts or something), it may not and has to be recycled (or time'd out).

You can always enforce a restart of your applications pool through powershell, **without** restarting IIS:

```
IIS:\>Restart-WebAppPool <YourPoolName>
```